# Using lapply to convert a single dataframe column to numeric in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of dataframes,  each df having three columns all of which are of type `character`. What I want is to use `lapply` (or another`*apply` function) and `as.numeric` to convert the 'heart attack' column to numeric but to also preserve the other variables in each dataframe.

Here is sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(AK = structure(list(hospital = c("HOS_3", "HOS_4"
), state = c("AK", "AK"), `heart attack` = c("13.4", "17.7")), .Names = c("hospital", 
"state", "heart attack"), row.names = 3:4, class = "data.frame"), 
AL = structure(list(hospital = c("HOS_1", "HOS_2"), state = c("AL", 
"AL"), `heart attack` = c("14.3", "18.5")), .Names = c("hospital", 
"state", "heart attack"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
AR = structure(list(hospital = c("HOS_5", "HOS_6"), state = c("AR", 
"AR"), `heart attack` = c("15.6", "16.9")), .Names = c("hospital", 
"state", "heart attack"), row.names = 5:6, class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR"))
```

Looks like this:

```
> data
$AK
hospital state heart attack
3    HOS_3    AK         13.4
4    HOS_4    AK         17.7

$AL
hospital state heart attack
1    HOS_1    AL         14.3
2    HOS_2    AL         18.5

$AR
hospital state heart attack
5    HOS_5    AR         15.6
6    HOS_6    AR         16.9
```

I want the exact same structure back but just with 'heart attack' column as numeric. Here is what I have tried so far (based on other SO posts and the ?docs and playing around) and a comment explaining what is going wrong:

```
lapply(c, function(x) x[3] <- as.numeric(x[[3]])) # returns list of num vectors. Dropped other cols
lapply(c, function(x) x[[3]] <- as.numeric(x[[3]])) # returns list of num vectors. Dropped other cols
rapply(c, as.numeric, classes = 'character', how='list') # Correct structure in output but converts all other cols to NA
sapply(c, function(x) x[,3] <- as.numeric(x[,3])) # returns list of num vectors. Dropped other cols
lapply(c, function(x) lapply(x[,3], as.numeric)) # returns list of num vectors of single length
lapply(c, lapply, as.numeric([[3]])) # error unexpected '[[
lapply(c, function(x) {x[[3]] <- as.numeric(x[[3]])})# returns list of num vectors. Dropped other cols
lapply(c, lapply, as.numeric, [,3]) # error unexpected '[
```

Help much appreciated! Also, I would like to just use base R (if possible) so would prefer not to have to bring in another library (security issues at work - they don't always allow). Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, you just need to return the complete dataframe back after changing one column. So if you want to change the class of column by name do

```
data <- lapply(data, function(x) {x$`heart attack` <- as.numeric(x$`heart attack`);x})
```

Or if you want to change the class by position do

```
data <- lapply(data, function(x) {x[[3]] <- as.numeric(x[[3]]);x})
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. This works but throws a warning with the '[]' after `data` but removing this removes the warning. I will accept answer but maybe you can edit? Thanks very much

Comment: ohh..well this is list so you don't need `[]` but it didn't give me any warning message for the `data` shared.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a way to make it work with rapply?

Comment: I am not sure if `rapply` can be used here since `rapply` is used to recursively apply a function to list, here it is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Another `base` solution that combines `lapply` with `within`:

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) within(x,{`heart attack`<-
                               as.numeric(`heart attack`)}))
$AK
  hospital state heart attack
3    HOS_3    AK         13.4
4    HOS_4    AK         17.7

$AL
  hospital state heart attack
1    HOS_1    AL         14.3
2    HOS_2    AL         18.5

$AR
  hospital state heart attack
5    HOS_5    AR         15.6
6    HOS_6    AR         16.9
```

To confirm that the above works:

```
List of 3
 $ AK:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ hospital    : chr [1:2] "HOS_3" "HOS_4"
  ..$ state       : chr [1:2] "AK" "AK"
  ..$ heart attack: num [1:2] 13.4 17.7
 $ AL:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ hospital    : chr [1:2] "HOS_1" "HOS_2"
  ..$ state       : chr [1:2] "AL" "AL"
  ..$ heart attack: num [1:2] 14.3 18.5
 $ AR:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ hospital    : chr [1:2] "HOS_5" "HOS_6"
  ..$ state       : chr [1:2] "AR" "AR"
  ..$ heart attack: num [1:2] 15.6 16.9
```

For `tidyverse` users, we can do the same as follows:

```
purrr::map(df_list,purrr::modify_at(~.x,3,as.numeric))
$AK
  hospital state heart attack
3    HOS_3    AK         13.4
4    HOS_4    AK         17.7

$AL
  hospital state heart attack
1    HOS_1    AL         14.3
2    HOS_2    AL         18.5

$AR
  hospital state heart attack
5    HOS_5    AR         15.6
6    HOS_6    AR         16.9
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `transform`

```
data <- lapply(data, transform, `heart attack` = as.numeric(`heart attack`))
str(data)
#List of 3
# $ AK:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ hospital    : chr [1:2] "HOS_3" "HOS_4"
#  ..$ state       : chr [1:2] "AK" "AK"
#  ..$ heart.attack: num [1:2] 13.4 17.7
# $ AL:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ hospital    : chr [1:2] "HOS_1" "HOS_2"
#  ..$ state       : chr [1:2] "AL" "AL"
#  ..$ heart.attack: num [1:2] 14.3 18.5
# $ AR:'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ hospital    : chr [1:2] "HOS_5" "HOS_6"
#  ..$ state       : chr [1:2] "AR" "AR"
#  ..$ heart.attack: num [1:2] 15.6 16.9
```

---

Or using `map` with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(data, ~ .x %>%
              mutate(`heart attack` = as.numeric(`heart attack`)))
```